# I am trying to show csv totals on a datagridview

Tags: visual-studio, powershell

I am trying to show csv totals on a `datagridview` but it doesn't seem to like it.
please see below code

```
$button70_Click = {
$rows = Import-Csv -Path "C:\Users\Name\Desktop\Testsdarts\301leader.csv" 
$rows | Group-Object Player | 
Select-Object Name, @{ n='Wins'; e={ ($_.Group | Measure-Object Wins -Sum).Sum } }
$dataGridView1.DataSource=[System.Collections.ArrayList]$rows
}
```

please see below how my `csv` is laid out

[image]

as you can see it works perfectly in Powershell ISE

[image]

but the `datagridview` doesn't, is there any way to get the ISE output in the `datagridview`?

[image]

Comment: Put `$rows =` in front of `$rows | Group-Object Player ...` - otherwise the grouped values are never stored in `$rows`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the code, the gridview takes its input data from the `$rows` variable - so you need to ensure you actually *store* the output from the `Group-Object`/`Select-Object` pipeline in `$rows` by using the `=` assignment operator:

```
$rows = $rows | Group-Object Player | Select-Object Name, @{ n='Wins'; e={ ($_.Group | Measure-Object Wins -Sum).Sum } }
# ^ remember to assign the modified data back to the variable
```